# Send decimal type to controller

Tags: c#

i have a problem to send decimal value to controller. Input in text box looks like 25.15 but controller not receive a value, but then i send 25,15 it is ok. I try solve it with Javascript, but it not helped for me.

```
$('form#item input[mytag]').each(function () {
        var input = $(this);
        var value = input.val();
        var replace = value.replace(/\./g, ',');
        console.log(replace);
    });
```

my controller looks like

```
public ActionResult Create(UnloadOrder UnloadOrder)
    {
        UnloadOrder.QuantityKg.ToString().Replace('.', ',');
        UnloadOrder.QuantityLtr.ToString().Replace('.', ',');
        UnloadOrder.QuatityLtr15C.ToString().Replace('.', ',');
            var suc = Db.Database.SqlQuery<UnloadOrder>("spr_UnloadOrder_insert @EventDateTime, @RecordDateTime, @MaterialID, @QuantityKg, @QuantityLtr, @QuatityLtr15C",
            new SqlParameter("EventDateTime", DateTime.ParseExact(UnloadOrder.EventDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
            new SqlParameter("RecordDateTime", UnloadOrder.RecordDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
            new SqlParameter("MaterialID", UnloadOrder.MaterialID),
            new SqlParameter("QuantityKg", UnloadOrder.QuantityKg.HasValue ? UnloadOrder.QuantityKg : (object)DBNull.Value),
            new SqlParameter("QuantityLtr", UnloadOrder.QuantityLtr.HasValue ? UnloadOrder.QuantityLtr : (object)DBNull.Value),
            new SqlParameter("QuatityLtr15C", UnloadOrder.QuatityLtr15C.HasValue ? UnloadOrder.QuatityLtr15C : (object)DBNull.Value)).ToList();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Please help. Thanks. Sorry for English :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what does your controller look like?

Comment: How to send 25.15 as double type to controller? because then i send 25,15 it is ok

Comment: You should respect the `CultureInfo` of the binding thread

Comment: How do you send data to your controller? How is `UnloadOrder` populated?

Comment: with Jquery $("#myform").submit();

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131414/culture-invariant-decimal-tryparse