# comma on price value is not being read

Tags: asp.net, type-conversion, textbox, string.format

i have implemented a price text box wherein it shows 12,345 instead of 12345. Or sometimes. 12,345.00. However when being submitted to the database, it shows 12345. the comma is gone. any tricks on this? here is my place order button code:

```
 protected void btnPlaceOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string productids = string.Empty;
        DataTable dt;
        if (Session["MyCart"] != null)
        {
            dt = (DataTable)Session["MyCart"];

            decimal totalPrice, totalProducts;
            bool totalPriceConversionResult = decimal.TryParse(txtTotalPrice.Text, out totalPrice), totalProductsConversionResult = decimal.TryParse(txtTotalProducts.Text, out totalProducts);


            ShoppingCart k = new ShoppingCart()
            {
                CustomerName = txtCustomerName.Text,
                CustomerEmailID = txtCustomerEmailID.Text,
                CustomerAddress = txtCustomerAddress.Text,
                CustomerPhoneNo = txtCustomerPhoneNo.Text,
                TotalProducts = totalProductsConversionResult ? Convert.ToInt32(totalProducts) : 0,
                TotalPrice = totalPriceConversionResult ? Convert.ToInt32(totalPrice) : 0,
                ProductList = productids,
                PaymentMethod = rblPaymentMethod.SelectedItem.Text

            };
            DataTable dtResult = k.SaveCustomerDetails();

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) // loop on how many products are added by the user
            {
                ShoppingCart SaveProducts = new ShoppingCart()
                {
                    CustomerID = Convert.ToInt32(dtResult.Rows[0][0]),
                    ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ProductID"]),
                    TotalProducts = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["ProductQuantity"]),
                };
                SaveProducts.SaveCustomerProducts();
            }
            var customerId = Convert.ToInt32(dtResult.Rows[0][0]);
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("OrderSummary.aspx?Id={0}", customerId.ToString()));
```

Any tricks that i can do on the total price?

I tried using string.format to try if it will get 12,345 but i failed. here is the code:

```
lblTotalProducts.Text = Convert.ToString(dtCustomerDetails.Rows[0][String.Format("{0:#,000.00}","TotalProducts")]);
```

this line of code above will get data from the database.

Comment: TryParse needs the internationalization parameter set, so that you can force what the meening of . and , (different languages swap them around)

Comment: can you help me out sir @StianSkjelstad

Comment: @StianSkjelstad i just need the commas to be shown in the database. so that when i get data from database, it will show the right format. 12,345

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23131414/culture-invariant-decimal-tryparse   This one shows some examples of Decimal.TryParse(). Same logic applies to most of the TryParse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In numeric data storage, the comma thousand separator is insignificant. It is only a presentation artifact. In your case, let the database store the value as `12345`, but display it as `12,345.00` using `string.Format` method. Please see [Standard Numeric Formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

edit: `lblTotalProducts.Text = String.Format("{0:#,000.00}",dtCustomerDetails.Rows[0]["TotalPr‌​oducts"]);`

Comment: i understand. but when i get the value from database, i want it to be 12,345

Comment: like for example here: lblTotalPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(dtCustomerDetails.Rows[0]["TotalPrice"]); this code gets the data from the database

Comment: @PaoloDuhaylungsod So, it is on this line that you need to format it (using `string.Format`) to include the thousand separator. For example, `string.Format("{0:#,000.00}", 12345)`.

Comment: whats wrong with this? lblTotalProducts.Text = Convert.ToString(dtCustomerDetails.Rows[0][String.Format("{0:#,000.00}","TotalProducts"]); error is ) expected

Comment: (Now, we are getting in spood-feeding territory.) The error message says it, you have a misplaced `)`. Get the value separately as you would normally before calling `string.Format` on it.

Comment: OK. Start at the beginning. Try `string.Format("{0:#,000.00}", 12345)` then work from there.

Comment: please do see my edited question sir.  i have lblTotalProducts.Text = Convert.ToString(dtCustomerDetails.Rows[0][String.Format("{0:#,000.00}","TotalProducts")]);

Comment: `lblTotalProducts.Text = String.Format("{0:#,000.00}",dtCustomerDetails.Rows[0]["TotalPr‌​oducts"]); `

Comment: worked for me sir. thank you. post your answer so i can accept it.